# Are variables inside different scopes of the same function using the same memory? C

Tags: c, memory

If inside a function I have the following variables:

```
{
    int a;
};

{
    int b;
};
```

Will then `&a` be equal to `&b`?

Comment: Maybe yes, maybe no. It is not defined by the standard. Counting on it would lead to undefined behavior.

Comment: Did you try it yourself? I.e. for your compiler, are they the same? If so the asnwer may be yes but don’t rely on it.

Comment: @barny The information gained from this experiment is pretty useless.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I've tried to say that to people before, that once you're in the realm of UB, any new information is pointless.  They always insist that the exercise helps their understanding. `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Not a single one of the laws of physics is defined in any documentation we were given, all of physics is “undefined behavior,” yet experimentation has yield tremendously valuable information about them. Experiments can help understanding. They cannot be fully authoritative, but they can be informative and illuminating. Nonetheless, barny’s comment is off target; students should neither be chastised for not performing an experiment that cannot be authoritative nor for performing an experiment that might be informative.

Comment: @EricPostpischil physics is a non changing system (or at least this is how it's studied) a compiler is something made by humans that can be different from one another, the documentation is the only way to determine if something is in a compiler 100% or not.

Comment: @EugeneSh. See what I mean?

Comment: @GuillemVS: Physics is “non-changing” only in the sense we model it with rules that separate variants and invariants. Certainly environments vary tremendously in temperature, pressure, gravity, materials present, and more, and it look a great deal of time to work out common laws. What you are getting at with asserting documentation is the only way (it is not) to determine if something is in a compiler “100% or not” is what I said by authoritative. But experiments can still be informative, as I wrote. (But documents can be wrong, and compilers can be studied by examining their executables.)

Comment: @GuillemVS: E.g., the acceleration of falling objects on Mars is not the same as the acceleration of falling objects on Earth. Physics is not the the same in these different places. We model it with one invariant law and variant parameters (mass of a nearby large body). Similarly, somebody experimenting with C compilers would discover things that vary and things that did not and would sort them into various laws.

Comment: @EricPostpischil physics is non-changing. that's the way we study physics. I'm not talking about parameters, gravity, pressure etc. I'm talking about the equations, the generalization of the behaviour of this universe is non changing (or at least this is how we study it). It's important to do experiments because we know it won't change from one another within the same parameters, however, in terms of compilers it may vary if it's not on the documentation, therefore, it's useless to test.

Comment: @GuillemVS: We do not **know** whether physics is non-changing or not. But this point is irrelevant. Experiments can tell us things whether the rules are changing it not, both with physics and with compilers. If all the available compilers at one time behave according to some hypothesized rule and, over the course of a few years, new versions of them are produced that behave differently, we can infer things from that. Remember, the point is not that experiments can produce rules we are absolutely certain of but that they can produce some information and reveal some patterns.

Comment: @EricPostpischil exactly, I don't have all the compilers in the world, I don't even have two. Can't create a rule, can't find pattern, hence, the experiment is useless.

Comment: @GuillemVS: Every behavior of a single compiler is a data point. If I find duplicate outputs from `{ int a; printf("%p\n", (void *) &a); } { int b; printf("%p\n", (void *) &b); }`, that is evidence two objects with non-overlapping lifetimes are not prohibited from using the same space. So, no, experiments are not useless.

Comment: @GuillemVS: This is not about expecting a program to work. As I have stated repeatedly, this is not about **authoritative** information, the documentation needed to provide assurance that a program will behave as designed. It is about **learning**. Students cannot learn everything all at once, and they cannot understand the C standard or other documents without learning preliminary concepts, and they cannot learn solely from prose stating rules. Part of the way humans learn is by experience, by doing, and performing experiments and connecting abstract rules to concrete things they can touch.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221241/discussion-between-guillemvs-and-eric-postpischil).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ISO-C-standard answer is that we cannot tell. Since `a` and `b` are not in the same scope, we cannot evaluate an expression which contains both `&a` and `&b`. Moreover, the following trick to get around that is undefined behavior:

```
int *pa, *pb;

{
   int a;
   pa = &a;
}

{
   int b;
   pb = &b;
}

// these pointer values are indeterminate; using them is
// undefined behavior.
pa == pb;
```

But yes, compilers can and do reduce the storage for local variables in that way. It can be important if some of those variables are large-ish arrays. Though formally undefined behavior, the `pa == pb` comparison will *de facto* work in just about any compiler, making it possible to investigate the issue, though the best way to be sure is to obtain an assembly language listing of the generated code and read that.

Suppose you have some `DEBUG_PRINT` macro which expands to a block of code that declares a local `char buf[512]` array. If that is used numerous times in a function, it would be poor to have that many repetitions of the buffer reserved in the stack frame. The same remarks apply to inline functions.

Comment: Well, we *can* make experiments without invoking UB - by printing out the values for example. But the information gained is not very useful.

Comment: "Since a and b are in the same scope..:" Not, you mean?